# How to store images in Marklogic and serve it in search

Tags: marklogic

How to store images in Marklogic server using xquery and how to search by creating a application using application builder

Answer (score 3):

Well, for loading content into MarkLogic, take a look at Content Pump.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump

Images are just blobs, so to make them useful and have something to search on, you can use MarkLogic's document filtering to extract text and metadata from binaries.  See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/binary-document-metadata

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-filter?q=document-filter

The extracted metadata will be a document in MarkLogic, as will be the image.  (Refer to http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/binaries on configuring where the binaries are stored in relation to being managed by MarkLogic.)

You can also just enable Content Processing for your database and enable the "Document Filtering (XHTML)" pipeline to automatically extract metadata from the binaries and insert an XHTML doc as the images are ingested.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/overview

You can then build an AppBuilder app on top of the extracted metadata docs.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-builder/intro

Depending on how you want to expose facets and other info from the metadata, you may want to model the documents a bit differently than what the filtering output provides ootb.

Assuming the image is managed by MarkLogic, and the associated extracted metadata is in MarkLogic as a separate document, you'll need to link the related resources somehow.  Depending on how you want to expose the metadata and their images in the application, you could just place the URI for the image location in MarkLogic in another field within the extracted metadata doc, so as the doc is queried/searched/discovered, your app can just leverage the metadata to fetch the related image.

Hope this helps,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

The detailed answer from Pete Aven gives a lot of inside details. There is also an existing sample app however, that is probably worth mentioning here:

http://developer.marklogic.com/code/document-discovery

HTH!